# AS3, AIR. Font to ByteArray?

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, binary

I need to pass an embedded Font from one air app, to another.

The way that I'm thinking is bulk to ByteArray the Font, and make the inverse once the ByteArray arrived to the second app.

It's possible to convert an embedded Font to ByteArray, and then regenerate the Font with that data?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. Can you explain how exactly it your app should work? Maybe there is some other way to achieve it...

Comment: Yes, off course: I'm dealing with two air apps, connected via socket. I need to transfer some objects in real time, from server to client. One of the objects to transfer is a Font type, to be applied to a TextFormat inside the client app. Any idea? thanks!

Comment: Can't you just use another swf and load it to the air app?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong: Your idea is: 1. Embed the font in a swf. 2. Load the swf in the server app. 3. Transfer the swf from the server to the client?

Comment: Yep, something like that.